# IE 8 - mouse over an img affects ul

Tags: css, internet-explorer, mouseover

```
<div>
<ul class="ulCont">
<li><a href="#nogo">Sky</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Sea</a></li>
</ul>
<img class="thinker01" src="images/thinker01.png"/>
<div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ulCont{float:left;}
.thinker01{float:right;}
.thinker01:hover{margin-top:-5px;}
.clearBoth{clear:both;}
```

Firefox and Chrome - works well, i.e. `img` is moved on mouseover, and `ul` stays in place.
IE8 - when mouseover `img` - it also moves `ul` up to -5px top margin.
So, could someone set an embargo on IE production ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this works in all browsers for me.  Please, check

```
<div>
<ul class="ulCont">
<li><a href="#nogo">Sky</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Sea</a></li>
</ul>
<div style="clear:right;"></div> // this line is added
<img class="thinker01" src="images/thinker01.png"/>
<div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks MiniRagnarok. What about Issa ?

Answer (score 1):

I just made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FmJ4E/1/) of what you gave me. I've tried what you're talking about in all three browsers. They all move up `-5px` on hover just like you told it to.

Comment: MiniRagnarok, I visited your jsfiddle with all the three browsers and found exactly the same result as previous: in FF and Chrome the list doesn't move and in IE8 - it moves up. Could someone else check this, pls ?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get any movement in IE8 for the hover.  This is because hover works in IE only for "a" tags with an href.

W3Schools says you can get it work with the appropriate DOCTYPE but I'm not sure which one.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

You can add the a tag around your image.

```
<a href="#nogo" class="thinker01"><img src="images/thinker01png_round_coaster.jpg"/></a>
```

and remove the border with

```
.thinker01 img {border: none;}
```

I realize this extra "a" may cause other problems but it might be a start to your solution.

Comment: @Issa I updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FmJ4E/2/) with your solution and it still moves up in IE8.

Comment: I didn't user jsfiddle.  Just tested html on my harddrive.  I guess that's why it didn't move.  Anyway looks like problem is solved.